# Do loop practice?

Tags: c#, loops, while-loop

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int output = 0;
            int number = 0;
            Console.WriteLine("Please input a number for it to be counted!");
            bool conversion = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out output);
            if( number >= 1000)
            {
                while (number <= output)
                {
                    switch (conversion)
                    {
                        case true:
                            Console.Write(number + " ");
                            number += 2;
                            break;
                        case false:
                            Console.WriteLine("ERROR INVALID INPUT!");
                            break;

                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("APPLICATION ERROR: NUMBER MUST BE BELOW OR AT 1000 TO PREVENT OVERFLOW!");
            }
            string choice = Console.ReadLine();
          do                                        // Here is the beginning of the do code
          {
              Console.WriteLine("Do you want to continue - Yes or No");
              if(choice.ToUpper() != "NO" && choice.ToUpper() != "NO");
              {
                  Console.WriteLine("ERROR INVALID INPUT: Only input Yes or No!");
              }
          }while(choice.ToUpper() != "YES" && choice.ToUpper() != "NO");
        }
    }
}
```

This is a very simple application and is unfinished but what it does is you put in a number below or equal to 1000 and it counts up to it evenly. My only problem is with the do statement at the end of the code. Its unfinished but from what I've researched that do statement is completed what happens is if the user does not input yes or no it will show them that error and then ask again "do you want to go again" However because of this do statement I put in any number like 10 and it gives me the error saying its over 1000 and then goes on an infinite loop of saying "ERROR INVALID INPUT: ONLY INPUT YES OR NO!" How can I fix this?

Comment: Wow, using a `switch()` statement on a boolean inside a loop. Spectacularly a WTF.

Answer (score 0):

Your if statement tests for NOT EQUAL to "no" twice, I assume you mean to check for not equal to "YES" and not equal to "NO"

Answer (score 0):

You have several issues in the code:

First, your condition checks that `number` is GREATER than or equal to 1000. Since you're entering `10`, which is not `>= 1000`, then you get to the `else` statement. So you need to change your condition to:

```
if(number <= 1000)
```

Next, your condition in the `do` loop checks the same condition twice... you don't allow the user to enter "yes". You should modifiy the condition to include a check for "yes". Also, you need to remove the semi-colon from the end of that same `if` statement:

```
do
{
    Console.WriteLine("Do you want to continue - Yes or No");
    choice = Console.ReadLine(); 

    if(choice.ToUpper() != "NO" && choice.ToUpper() != "NO");
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ERROR INVALID INPUT: Only input Yes or No!");            
    }
} while(choice.ToUpper() != "YES" && choice.ToUpper() != "NO");
```

One thing you also might consider is adding a method to get an integer from the user, since it is handy to wrap it in some validation:

```
public static int GetIntFromUser(string prompt,
    string errorMessage = "Invalid entry. Please try again.")
{
    int value;

    while (true)
    {
        if (prompt != null) Console.Write(prompt);
        if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out value)) break;
        if (errorMessage != null) Console.WriteLine(errorMessage);
    }

    return value;
}
```

Then, you can call this method when you need to get an int from the user. Here's a sample of how it could be used:

```
private static void GenericTester()
{
    // This will flag that the user wants to quit
    bool quit = false;

    while(!quit)
    {
        // Get input from user
        int userInput = GetIntFromUser("Please input a number to be counted: ");
        int number = 0;

        // Write out the numbers
        if (userInput <= 1000)
        {
            while (number <= userInput)
            {
                Console.Write(number + " ");
                number += 2;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("APPLICATION ERROR: NUMBER MUST BE BELOW " +
                "OR AT 1000 TO PREVENT OVERFLOW!");
        }

        // See if they want to continue
        while (true)
        {
            // Get user input
            Console.Write("Do you want to continue - Yes or No: ");
            string choice = Console.ReadLine();

            // If they said 'No', set flag to quit and break out of this loop
            if (choice.Equals("No", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                quit = true;
                break;
            }

            // If they said 'Yes', just break out of this loop
            if (choice.Equals("Yes", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) break;

            // Otherwise, display an error message and let the loop continue
            Console.WriteLine("ERROR INVALID INPUT: Only input Yes or No!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay I've fixed that and it counts the numebr but after that when I press anything it goes back into an infinite loop! When I put in the number and it counts it it then leaves me blank space where I have nothing to do but  press a key and when I press it it spams "ERROR INVALID INPUT!" EDIT: I fixed it I accidentally placed string choice = Console.Readline(); above the message. Anyways I put in yes or no and it tells me "error invalid input!!" what could cause this?

Comment: You also have to get 'choice' from the user again (inside the do loop). I've updated the sample.

Comment: Beautiful thank you. I also managed to fix some of the other bugs by correcting my bad programming placement. However, it now spams me with INVALID INPUT YES OR NO if I put something other than yes or no.  And it also tells me error invalid input please put yes or no! Even if I put that! EDIT: Okay so I managed to get it working now all that's left is the explaining. Could you please tell me why I have to re-declare choice being Console.Readline(); ?

Comment: because you need to get a new value assigned to 'choice' each time you loop, until you get the one you want. I've updated the answer with an additional sample that might help.

Answer (score 0):

Your infinite loop is because the condition checks the content of `choice`, but you never change the value of the variable within the do loop - only in the `Console.ReadLine()` immediately before the loop starts.

You should start the do loop before the code you want to be repeated. For instance, if your intent is that if the user types yes that the entire process repeats, you may be best served by creating a void function, say `static void CountNumbers() { ... }` that has all the code doing your input on how high to count, error handling, etc. Then you can use your do loop to easily repeat as much as the user wants, like this:

```
string choice = null;
do
{
    CountNumbers();
    // Your code here to ask if user wants to continue and readline to get the new choice
} while ( /* Existing condition */);
```